# How to fix 301 redirect that is not working

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirect from https://www.compareking.no/penger/kredittkort to https://www.compareking.no/forbrukslaan but nothing is happening when I modify the htacess file.

This is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.compareking.no/penger/kredittkort$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// www.compareking.no/forbrukslaan/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: make sure you restart the server and clear your browsers cache.  I've had that burn me before.

Comment: The "htacess" file should be named `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_HOST only matches the HOST/domain part of the URL, that specified in RewriteCond and the URI prefix in RewriteRule would get you on the right track, as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.compareking\.no$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^penger/kredittkort(.*)$ http://www.compareking.no/forbrukslaan$1 [L,R=301]
```